# Oracle to_timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

quick question on **Oracle To_timestamp.**

I have a two fields in a table that are both varchars

1 field contains the YYYYMMDD formatted value
the 2nd field contains the hh24mmss formatted value

Im trying to convert these two fields into a timestamp field,

expected output is DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mm:ss
like '7/23/2015 12:53:04'

however, it gaves me weird result...
like '7/15/0023 12:53:04'

seems year becomes day and day becomes year..

---------- heres my sql ----------------

```
select 


  to_date(to_char(to_date('20150723','yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd') dt,
  to_char(to_date(SUBSTR('005304000',1,6), 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss') tm,

 TO_TIMESTAMP(
 to_date(to_char(to_date('20150723','yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd'),'yyyymmdd')  ||  
 to_char(to_date(SUBSTR('005304000',1,6), 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'  ) dttm

  from dual
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one layer to much in your conversion chain. And it will be much easier if you concatenate the two columns before converting them:

```
to_date(date_column||time_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

will return a date and a time (an Oracle `DATE` includes a time part).

Now that you have a proper date value, you can then format that as you want:

```
to_char(to_date(date_column||time_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

As your "time" column doesn't contain milliseconds there is no real benefit in using `to_timestamp`.

---

But you should **really** fix your table, and store that information in a single `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) column. Storing dates in `varchar` columns is always a very bad choice.

Comment: Yeah. i think i miss that part of concat the date/time first before doing conversion.. this table is a load from flat file and cannot change..

Comment: @delroekid: you also have an unnecessary `to_date()` call on the result of the `to_char()`